# How to make the same hover like the other tr's

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm having a trouble that I don't understand.
I want the same hover for all TR's, the right one is the hover that is working on CELL B

Can somebody to explain me, where is the error?

This is my hover CSS:

```
.table-hover tr:hover,
.table-hover tr td:hover {
    background-color: #595959!important;
    color: #fff;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/luiggi/uR22x/3/

Comment: Thanks to everyone, if you need something ... you can contact with me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uR22x/4/)

Your problem was this:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th{
    background-color: #f9f9f9!important;
}
```

- Your style didn't overwrite this, notice in the fiddle I also changed:

  .table-hover tr td:hover

to this:

```
.table-hover tr:hover td
```

Because you want to change all TD's under the :hovered TR.. right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `!important` anywhere, better apply hover effect for tr:

```
table tr:hover td {
    background-color: #595959;
}
```

Comment: !important it's to rewrite bootstrap css rules

Answer (score 0):

you have implementd some css in odd tr with this your main functionality will be disturb.that's why it working only on even tr.

```
*so ,remove following line from css* 

.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
```